# Ruby on Rails: Need Recommendations for Wizards/Spring Webflow-type Solutions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, wizard, spring-webflow, formwizard

I'm starting work on a multi-page web application using Ruby on Rails 3. My webapp won't be using a database directly - it'll be calling a web service to persist the collected information.

Are there any equivalents to Spring Webflow that more advanced RoR developers would recommend? I've looked at examples for wizardly and actsaswizard. Both libraries seem to use ActiveRecord. A few co-workers have experimented with Spring Webflow, which seems to work well, but I'd really like to find a RoR solution. My team would be open to looking at a Rails 3.1 solution, if available.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/jcoglan/action_flow      (may take some rejigging for newer Rails)

http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=2769     (no docs, looks alpha)

Note the age and activity levels on each project though...